# Automator - Conversion from image files to Files/Folders failed

Tags: automator

I am trying to do a simple task of just taking a screenshot with automator and importing that screenshot into iPhoto.  The screenshot takes fine and saves it to the correct location.  It does save as a .png file but then I get an error when it goes to the next step of getting the specified finder items.  It fails and states `Conversion from Image files to Files/Folders failed` and `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.  See screenshot below.

My ultimate goal is to do a time lapse setup with automator.  Any thoughts on what may be causing this error?  I am running OSX 10.8.3

Thanks!

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to ignore input for `Get Specified Finder Items` action.

To do so, select `Options`, and check `Ignore this action's input`:

[image]